# Function does not exist while it does

Tags: php, console

I'm facing a problem. I'm currently facing a problem: I have a console php script which executes a function from user input. I have a class called `DefaultModelFactory` which has a static function `createSchema`. When I `var_dump(get_class_methods('DefaultModelFactory'))` I get the following output:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(12) "createSchema"
}
```

The user input is `DefaultModelFactory,createSchema` which I `explode(',', fgets(STDIN))` then I open a new STDIN for the parameters which I also explode by ',' characters then pass these inputs to this function:

```
function executeCommand($commandName, array $options){
    if(is_array($commandName)){
        if(method_exists($commandName[0],$commandName[1])){

            call_user_func_array(implode('::', $commandName), $options);
        }
        else{
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf("The function %s::%s does not exist!", $commandName[0], $commandName[1]));
        }
    }
    else{
        if(function_exists($commandName)){
            call_user_func_array($commandName, $options);
        }
        else{
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf("The function %s does not exist!", $commandName));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the exception is thrown. I also checked the php error:

> `PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'DefaultModelFactory' does not have a method 'createSchema
>   ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwwcapi\console.php on line 15`

The full code of console.php can be checked at [here](http://pastebin.com/4nSnarte/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [`var_dump($commandName)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) you'll see this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "DefaultModelFactory"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "createSchema
"
}
```

Note the line break at the index 1, the enter the user hits is sent to PHP as well. `call_user_func_array()` then tries to execute the function `createSchema\n`, which of course doesn't exist. So, remove the newline and any other unwanted whitespace the user might enter or paste with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
explode( ',', trim( fgets( STDIN ) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as a charm now!